# Symfony 2 | Влияние количества подключенных пакетов на скорость работы апликации

Tags: symfony2, symfony3

Добрый день.

Пишу свою админку и задаюсь вопросом. Если каждый модуль админки(Страницы, Новости, Меню, Слайдер и др) я создавал как отдельный пакет и все это подключалось бы в AppKernel. Сильно бы это повлияло на скорость моей апликации?

Сейчас все хранится непосредственно в AppBundle и имеет свою сущность и свой контроллер.

Все эти сущности, в общем, не особо между собой связаны и разный проект(сайт) мог бы иметь разный набор(где то есть новости, а где то нет и тд).

p.s. В Symfony я пока новичек.

Спасибо за ответы.

Comment: ко**л**ичества, приложения, нович**о**к

Comment: А что вы понимаете под "_скоростью аппликации_"?

Comment: @etki, день русского языка?)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev каждый день русского языка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony - это модульный фреймворк, а соответственно его основная идея заключается в том, что бы каждая, скажем так, "большая", логическая сущность (новости, личный кабинет ... ) были отдельный модулями - бандлами.

Так же в Symfony есть мощнейший инструмент - [DI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8), который должен помогать получать ту или иную сущность без особых сложностей. И если вы будете использовать DI на полную, то скорость (сложность) получения той или иной сущности будет достаточно быстрым

*Документация на [русском](http://files.abradabra.com/books/Symfony2_ru.pdf)*